# Synology - Users can delete the recycle bin

Tags: nas, synology, recycle-bin

Hello to the SuperUser's Community,

I have a question about the Synology Share's Recycle Bin.

**Username/Group/Folder/Rights**

- SuperUser/Administrators/Public/RWX
- User/Users/Public/RX

The SuperUser can modify (rename, move, etc...)
The User can only (read folders, and execute files)

The share named " Public " have the recycle bin function active with the option " Restrict access to Administrators only " checked.

When I log on using User's account to that share for example : \srv1\Public in Windows 7 x64 via **webDAV** using **netdrive**.

And I delete the recycle bin folder which is named as " **#RecycleBin** ", it let me delete it.

To approve that i went back \\srv1\ then i returned to \\srv1\Public and the folder " #RecycleBin " wasn't here anymore.

I double checked it by using **Web Station's** File Explorer and it wasn't there too.

How's that possible ? I mean User doesn't have rights to do that ?!

**My Synology Specs**

- DSM 6.0 u7
- RX3615xs
- 24 To
- BTRFS
- RAID 5
- SHR Volume